# How do i fix PUT 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to make a website where users can upload things to my server but when i try it it says

"PUT 405 (Method Not Allowed)"
here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Upload</h1>
<input id="file" type="file">

<br>
<button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
<hr>
</body>
<script>
function upload() {
    let data = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    let entry = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    console.log('doupload',entry,data)
    fetch('/files/' + encodeURIComponent(entry.name), {method:'PUT',body:data});
console.log(data)
console.log(entry)
}
</script>
</html>
```

BTW i use xampp on windows and windows file permitions are NOT read only

Answer (score 1):

Web servers do not generally come with built-in implementations of PUT.

Nobody wants any drive-by client to be able to write to their server (especially if they pick an existing URL and overwrite files that are already there!).

In order to support PUT you need to write server-side code to handle the request (and unless you are in a very unusual position you will need to include authentication and authorisation checks as part of that code).

Once you've written server side code to handle the request you can tell Apache HTTPD to allow them with [mod_allowmethods](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html).

Comment: can you please make an example for me as i added the mod allowmethods to apache but i do not understand how to handle the request

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language. Step 2: Learn how to do server side programming with it.